# 3d icons on top representation with direct x 9 in c++

Tags: visual-c++, directx, directx-9

I'm doing a simulator visual where I have a lot of 2D icons representing elements of the simulation and I have a 3D (.x made with Blender) icon which represents another and more important element.

I need to make this one on top of the other 2d icons (.tga) but I cannot find the way to make this. Is it possible for Direct x to draw a 3d icon over the rest of the 2d icons?. 
At this moment, the 2D icons apear on top of the 3D, always.

Could please someone help me with this. I'm programming in C++
Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Z-writes when you render the 2D icons.  When you then render the 3D icons with Z-writes enabled it will render OVER the 2D icons.

Your problem at present is that when you render the 2D icons you are doing so with a z value which is the front of the z-buffer (most probably 0).  You may also find you can set the z-value to 1 (again this is probably, it entirely depends on how you've set up your 2D rendering) to force the 2d icons to render at the back of the z buffer.

No entry in the Z-buffer is equivalent to it being at the back of the Z-order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have depth buffering enabled, you need to ensure that the Z value of your icons is further from your camera than your model.  If you are using ID3DXSprite, you should be able to specify the Z position when you call the Draw function, or by using the [ID3DXSprite::SetTransform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174258%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Note that ID3DXSprite may draw your sprites with a different projection matrix than your model, depending on the flags you pass to ID3DXSprite::Begin(). You might want to use the [D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205466%28VS.85%29.aspx) flag.